# Parse Python script on Apache virtual host

Tags: apache, python, centos

I have an up and running Apache server working with PHP on a Centos 6 server.  Apache was installed using `yum -y install httpd mod_ssl`.  I now wish to add Python.

I installed Python as follows:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
cd Python-3.3.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

I installed mod_python using `yum install mod_python`.

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` includes the following line `Include conf.d/*.conf`, so then I know that `/etc/httpd/conf.d/python.conf` has been included.  I made no changes to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/python.conf`, and the only un-commented directives are:

```
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
<Directory "/var/www/manual/mod/mod_python">
        <Files *.html>
                SetHandler default-handler
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

I then added the following VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/python/html
    <Directory /var/www/python/html/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      AddHandler mod_python .py
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
    </Directory>
    AddHandler mod_python .py    
    #DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.py
</VirtualHost>
```

If I access `http://example.com/testphp.php`, it is parsed as PHP, however, if I access `http://example.com/testpython.py`, it returns a `404 Not Found` error.  If I comment out `PythonHandler mod_python.publisher`, it returns the Python script un-parsed.

How do I use Python on a virtual host?

EDIT.  If `testpython.py` consists of script `print( 'xxxx' )`, I get the 404 error.  If it consists of the following, it returns `Test successful`.

```
def index(req):
  return "Test successful";
```

Both produce the following notice in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Mon Dec 07 07:03:14 2015] [notice] mod_python (pid=16441, interpreter='example.com'): Importing module '/var/www/python/html/testpython.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use mod_python yet, but it seems to me that the script is expected to *return* (rather than print) the text to be served, and to contain an `index` function to accomplish this.

If you don't define the `index` function, `mod_python` won't know what to do about your module.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check:

1. The script is executable
2. `var-www` has permission to access it

Check the permissions on the script.  They could be set such that only root can read it.